# Regex to find for A group of character and at max 3 numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have special condition where I need to remove a group of a(only one) character `[A-Z]` (caps only), followed by a number that can be 3 digits at max.

For example - from  I/P : `BA1040,E123,ZA650,B12`
Output should be : E123 and B12 only and I should reject others like A1040 and A650 etc.

It should also reject if there is a character/number which is followed by a character and then the numbers. e.g. ZA650 should not work. It would have worked if that was A650 or Z650 only.

I tried various things, Simple expression like `[A-Z]\d+` also gives me wrong output.

Can someone help me here ?

Comment: What exactly are you doing?  Regular expressions do not "give you output".  You are doing something with regular expressions to produce output.  What?

Comment: Well I know they do not give me output. I am looking for a particular expression inside a string thats why I am using Regular expressions :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `{m,n}` syntax to specify maximum or minimum repetition counts. Since you don't want to have a digit afterwards or a letter before, use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]\d{1,3}(?!\d)
```

This means:

```
(?<![A-Z]) -- (Negative lookbehind) Forbid `A-Z` before the match.
[A-Z]      -- A single capital letter.
\d{1,3}    -- At least 1 digit but not more than 3.
(?!\d)     -- (Negative lookahead) Forbid digit after the match.
```

Comment: It gives : A1040,E123,A650,B12 which I do not want

Comment: I see, you wanted to have at least one digit. So, I added a minimum digit count.

Comment: I wanted ONLY one digit, for at least one digit I solved it.

Comment: Hehe, it is not so easy when there can be other text. I have amended the answer again.

Comment: And here's the regex fiddle: http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDgsSBlJlY2lwZRjj43sM/index.html

Comment: Bam! that works. Can you explain it ?

Comment: Yeah its hard. that why I posted here :D Thanks man !

Comment: Explained, hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, what's with the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote !! Amazing someone did.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following  regex  `[A-Z]\d{0,3}`

EDIT -- `^[A-Z]\d{1,3}$`  if your search begins with `A-Z` and can have at least `1` and at most `3 digits`

Comment: Actually I tried that but it does not work. I just need E123 and B12 in the output if we see the input I have provided.

Comment: @user2480628 `3 digits at max` -- means 0, 1, 2, or 3 digits. So, what is the requirement here? Can you pls explain?

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match what (I think) you want (character followed by at most 3 digits) is:

```
[A-Z][0-9]{,3}
```

Comment: I just need one character followed by max 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern (written in java style) that use word boundaries

```
\\b[A-Z]\\d{1,3}\\b
```

More informations about word boundaries [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)